# Does anyone know what is this "typedef long long int (stoll_t)(const char *, char **, int);"?

Tags: c, c++14

I was going through a code base and found this

```
typedef long long int (stoll_t)(const char *, char **, int);
```

Don't know what it does?
And how to call this function ?

is how it is in code

```
long long int argtoll( const char *str, const char **end, stoll_t stoll); //this
```

Comment: ASHOK SINGH, As you were going through a code base, also posting later uses of `stow` would help in proving a specific answer.  Post some of the later uses of `stow` to and clarity to the question.

Comment: Good that you are improving your question, yet `long long int argtoll( const char *str, const char **end, stoll_t stoll);` does not contain `stow`.  Post some code that uses `stow`.

Comment: @chux thanks for pointhing that out . please see again if  you can help ?

Answer (score 1):

`typedef long long int (stow)(const char *, char **, int);` defines `stow` as a type.

That type is a [function (pointer to const char, pointer to pointer to char, int) returning long long int](https://cdecl.org/?q=long+long+int+%28stow%29%28const+char+*%2C+char+**%2C+int+%29).

```
long long int example_function_of_that_type(const char *a, char **b, int c) {
  if (a == NULL) return 1;
  if (b == NULL) return 2;
  return c;
}
```

Comment: Better explain how to use this type, because declaration is self explanatory

Comment: @P__J__ Perhaps, yet given the vagueness of OP's question, I thought rather than a tutorial on typedef-ing function pointers, I'd stick to a direct answer to OP's question.  Feel open to amend as you feel motivated.

Comment: And how to call this function ?

long long int argtoll( const char *str, const char **end,  stoll_t stoll);

this is how it is in code .

Comment: @chux it is not function pointer

Comment: @P__J__ True, and I did not answer that `stow` is a function pointer.

Comment: @ASHOKSINGH Best to put all your question in the original post, else this turns into an ongoing Q & A.

Comment: @chux okay I will

Answer (score -1):

It defines an alias to function type

it works like shorter version of the declaration of the extern function.

example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (stow)( int);

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    stow x;

    printf("%d\n", x(5));
    return 0;
}
```

and `x` has to be defined in other (or the same compilation unit).

Almost useless (at least I cant find any real use of it) - but definitely it makes code harder to read. So the only use is the code obfuscation or not hiding the function pointers.

`stow *y;` - does not hide the function pointer in the typedef.

Most programmers prefer actually to typedef the pointer to the function .

```
stow argtoll;

argtoll(/*... actual parameters */);
```